# Algorithm suggestion - search on number list

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 7 digit number list. And I am required to perform search operation on the list. Input of program will be like this 5xx9xx1 . Minimum 3 digits will be known. And index of known digits are not important. Which algorithm would you suggest? I don't  want to search on database with 'like' query.

Comment: Are the numbers unique?

Comment: Yes numbers are unique and list size is around 100k to 2 million

Comment: Naive algorithm: Iterate all the numbers and return the ones what match. What are your constraints, and what have you already tried? Are the numbers in the list ordered? Are you looking for any match or all matches?

Comment: So the three given digits can occur at any given position?

Comment: Actually I have to return list of numbers which are similar to given input. I tried in oracle using 'like'. But i dont want to use database..BTW thanks for interest

Comment: Is it always the same positions that are knows in the input?

Comment: No positions of known digits can change

Comment: I'd use a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and implement a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen care to elaborate what advantages that will have? The features in B-Tree doesn't seem to offer any particular advantages to this particular scenario. But that just might be my data structure ignorance speaking :-)

Comment: The B-Tree will have a fixed depth of 7 and a BFS algorithm will be quite fast in determining the numbers. Comparing to a wildcard search in the database a B-Tree should be significantly faster.

Comment: How about this: Group the numbers in the list into different sets: Numbers with a 1 at first position, numbers with a 2 at first position, numbers with a 7 at third position, etc. Once you have this, the rest is finding set intersections. You will have 70 such sets, but it might be worth it if you have to do many such lookups for the same list of numbers.

Comment: Actually b-tree seems better solution but searching on three is unclear for now. I try to understand BFS algorithm...

Comment: @tobias_k: That is essentially what a B-Tree is... :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to match elements on a collection with some wildcard search parameters will be to, iterate over the list and find the matching elements.

You also separate the lists and run the searches in parallel if that turns out to be too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the initial number list you have is sorted. If it is not sorted you're better off sorting it, since with a sorted list you can get the numbers with a pretty straight algorithm. However, if this is not a time critical operation you're better off using hash table or B-Tree data structure. The B-Tree can give you log(n) query time. It is easier to implement.

With a sorted list, you can jump to the correct elements directly, if the input specifies the positions and value of the search, ie if the input says look only for numbers that have `5`, `9` and `1` at positions `6`, `3` and `0` respectively, you can directly jump directly to index `5,000,000`, and you don't have to look for values beyond `5,999,999`.

The key insight lies in the fact that if you looking for a number(`I`) at position `X`, and you found the first such number `N` at that position, then the next consecutive `10^X-1` numbers will have `I` at the same position. The next set of number that will have `I` at `X` will be at index `N + 10 ^ (X+1)`.

For example if you're looking for numbers with `5` at position `2`, and if you're at say `10000500`, then you can read the next `10^2-1(99)` numbers in as something that will match that condition. The next set is at position `10000500 + 10^3 = 100001500`.

In your problem though you have multiple such conditions, so you start with the number at the highest position, and then go down further to smaller positions and jump to the number sets. If the next set you jump to is greater than the range allowed by the number at the immediately higher position, you jump to the value pointed by the number at the higher position.

For example, if you're looking for number with `5` at position `2` and `3` at position `1`, you start at `10000530`. The next `10^1` numbers will match your criterion. The next set for `3` alone will be at `10000530 + 10^2 = 10000630`, but that exceeds the limit set by `5` at position `2`, which is `99`. So you jump to the next set pointed by `5`, which is `10001530`.

This method is linear in time, w.r.to the output set, so you can have a huge input, and if your output is really small, the method will get out really fast. If you use the B-Tree or some such method they will be dependent on the input size.